# R: Performing operations for lists within lists

Tags: r, list

```
mylist = list(list(list(NULL, 2, 2), list(2, 3, NULL)), list(list(NULL, NULL, 2), list(NULL, 3, NULL)), list(list(2, 3, 2), list(NULL, 3, NULL)))

> mylist
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
NULL

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[1] 2

[[1]][[1]][[3]]
[1] 2


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] 2

[[1]][[2]][[2]]
[1] 3

[[1]][[2]][[3]]
NULL



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
NULL

[[2]][[1]][[2]]
NULL

[[2]][[1]][[3]]
[1] 2


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
NULL

[[2]][[2]][[2]]
[1] 3

[[2]][[2]][[3]]
NULL



[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[[3]][[1]][[1]]
[1] 2

[[3]][[1]][[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]][[1]][[3]]
[1] 2


[[3]][[2]]
[[3]][[2]][[1]]
NULL

[[3]][[2]][[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]][[2]][[3]]
NULL
```

`mylist` is a list object with `i = 3` lists in it. Within each `i` list, there are `j = 2` lists. And within each `j` list, there are `k = 3` elements.

The object can be indexed with `i, j, k`. For instance, `mylist[[1]][[1]][[1]] = NULL`.

I am interested in seeing the proportion of `NULL` within each `k` stratum across each `j` stratum.

Stratum **j = 1**

- For `j = 1` and `k = 1`, the proportion of `NULL` is 2/3 because `[[1]][[1]][[1]]` and `[[2]][[1]][[1]]` are `NULL`.
- For `j = 1` and `k = 2`, the proportion of `NULL` is 1/3 because `[[2]][[1]][[2]]` is `NULL`.
- For `j = 1` and `k = 3`, the proportion of `NULL` is 0.

Stratum **j = 2**

- For `j = 2` and `k = 1`, the proportion of `NULL` is 2/3 because `[[1]][[2]][[1]]` and `[[2]][[2]][[1]]` are `NULL`.
- For `j = 2` and `k = 2`, the proportion of `NULL` is 0
- For `j = 2` and `k = 3`, the proportion of `NULL` is 1 because `[[1]][[2]][[3]]`, `[[2]][[2]][[3]]` and `[[3]][[2]][[3]]` are all `NULL`.

In other words, I should get 6 proportions as the output. Is there an efficient way to access these list elements easily without having to write a loop? I've tried `apply(mylist, 2, function(x){sum(is.null(x))/length(x)})`, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`purrr`](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr) offers some nice utilities for working with lists that can make this kind of task simpler. Using 0.2.3,

```r
library(purrr)

mylist = list(list(list(NULL, 2, 2), list(2, 3, NULL)), 
              list(list(NULL, NULL, 2), list(NULL, 3, NULL)), 
              list(list(2, 3, 2), list(NULL, 3, NULL)))

mylist %>% 
    transpose() %>%    # flip each j element into an i element
    modify_depth(-1, is.null) %>%    # check if each leaf element is null
    # for each grouped set of j elements, iterate in parallel over k elements to find proportion TRUE
    map(pmap, ~sum(...) / length(c(...))) %>% 
    str()    # print nicely
#> List of 2
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ : num 0.667
#>   ..$ : num 0.333
#>   ..$ : num 0
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ : num 0.667
#>   ..$ : num 0
#>   ..$ : num 1
```

That said, if your data is effectively rectangular, may be a better idea to convert the `NULL` values to `NA`s so you can put it in a matrix, data.frame, or array, e.g.

```r
mylist %>% 
    modify_depth(-1, ~.x %||% NA_real_) %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    matrix(ncol = 3) %>% 
    is.na() %>% 
    {rowSums(.) / ncol(.)}
#> [1] 0.6666667 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.0000000 1.0000000
```

Converting it to a tidy data.frame is more work, but once completed makes very simple to manipulate:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- mylist %>% 
    modify_depth(-1, ~.x %||% NA_real_) %>%    # change NULL to NA
    set_names(paste0('i', 1:3)) %>%    # add names to become column names
    modify_depth(2, flatten_dbl) %>%    # flatten k values to vector
    as_data_frame() %>% 
    mutate(j = row_number()) %>%    # keep j index (which row each element is in)
    unnest() %>%    # expand
    group_by(j) %>% mutate(k = row_number()) %>%    # add k index
    gather(i, value, i1:i3) %>%    # reshape to long form
    mutate(i = parse_number(i)) %>%    # clean k values
    select(i, j, k, value) %>% ungroup()    # clean up

mydf %>% str()
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    18 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ i    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
#>  $ j    : int  1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...
#>  $ k    : int  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
#>  $ value: num  NA 2 2 2 3 NA NA NA 2 NA ...

mydf %>% 
    group_by(j, k) %>% 
    summarise(k_null = sum(is.na(value) / n()))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   j [?]
#>       j     k    k_null
#>   <int> <int>     <dbl>
#> 1     1     1 0.6666667
#> 2     1     2 0.3333333
#> 3     1     3 0.0000000
#> 4     2     1 0.6666667
#> 5     2     2 0.0000000
#> 6     2     3 1.0000000
```

Or use arrays, if you like:

```r
myarray <- mylist %>% 
    modify_depth(-1, ~.x %||% NA_real_) %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    array(c(3, 2, 3))

myarray
#> , , 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]   NA    2
#> [2,]    2    3
#> [3,]    2   NA
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]   NA   NA
#> [2,]   NA    3
#> [3,]    2   NA
#> 
#> , , 3
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    2   NA
#> [2,]    3    3
#> [3,]    2   NA

apply(is.na(myarray), 1:2, function(x){sum(x) / length(x)})
#>           [,1]      [,2]
#> [1,] 0.6666667 0.6666667
#> [2,] 0.3333333 0.0000000
#> [3,] 0.0000000 1.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it on my actual list (not this example) and I get an error of `Error: `x` must be a vector` when I tried to use `modify_depth`. Do you have an idea as to why that might happen?

Comment: When depth is set to `-1`, it iterates over the terminal nodes and applies the supplied function to them. The error is probably coming from the function, though I'm not sure what it would run into that wouldn't be a vector—the usual culprit is lists, but unless you have empty lists as terminal nodes that shouldn't be the problem. The same error could arise from `pmap`; you could coerce the `...` into a vector explicitly with `unlist`.

Answer (score 0):

Using base `R`:

```
test<-function(x)
{
    count=sum(sapply(x,function(t)is.null(t)))
    count/length(x)
}

sapply(1:2,function(t,mlist){
    sapply(1:3,function(u,t,mlist){
        test(
            sapply(
                sapply(mlist,"[[",t,simplify=F),
            "[[",u,simplify=T)
            )
    },t,mlist)},
    mylist,simplify = F)


#[[1]]
#[1] 0.6666667 0.3333333 0.0000000

#[[2]]
#[1] 0.6666667 0.0000000 1.0000000
```